# Re-order Divs without access to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm customising a wordpress theme and have come up against a frustrating blocker.

I would like to position the header (header.non-sticky-nav) after the fullscreen cover (.fullscreen-cover) and before the content (.content).

```
<header class="non-sticky-nav">
    <div id="navbar"></div>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="fullscreen-cover"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[current-result_vs_desired-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyu0U.jpg)

I tried repositioning the nav bar by using a "top: xpx" value but obviously that doesn't work as the .fullscreen-cover is not a fixed height.

Here is the test page I am using for the issue: http://samburrough.design/test/

The theme allows page specific or global css code injections, and as theme is regularly updated, I would like to try and stick to using this feature rather than delve into the theme files and have the changes overwritten every time I want to update.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: without the actual code it is hard to help. But can you do `.top-bar { padding-top: xxPX; } .other-bar { position: absolute; top:0 left:0; }`

Comment: Could you not create a child theme and modify the DOM that way? At least this way the changes won't be over-written every time an update to the parent theme is released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not create a child theme and modify the DOM that way?
At least this way the changes won't be over-written every time an update to the parent theme is released?

This would (should) actually be the preferred option.

[Smashing Magazine; Create and Customise Wordpress Child Theme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/)

Comment: I agree with this solution, it seems a lot better to rearrange the output structure in the layout elements, than to do a workaround.

Comment: Seems like this is the best option, but I was trying to avoid this as my knowledge is severely limited. I wouldn't have a clue how to find the correct php file!

Comment: @samjjb, I realise this places you out of your comfort zone, but really will be your best course of action - plus, you get to learn something new! If my answer helped, please mark it as the accepted answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if the theme does not include block positioning, you need to edit the DOM. While you could probably use some wonky absolute positioning on the bar and the hero, positioning them absolutely is likely to cause you a cascade of problems - starting with the responsive nav.

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript function/method that lets nodes swap places in the dom. 
you could try and look into that [Node.replaceChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)

The example below is from the documentation and creates a new element but you can also select an existing node.

```
// create an empty element node
// without an ID, any attributes, or any content
var sp1 = document.createElement("span");

// give it an id attribute called 'newSpan'
sp1.id = "newSpan";

// create some content for the new element.
var sp1_content = document.createTextNode("new replacement span element.");

// apply that content to the new element
sp1.appendChild(sp1_content);

// build a reference to the existing node to be replaced
var sp2 = document.getElementById("childSpan");
var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;

// replace existing node sp2 with the new span element sp1
parentDiv.replaceChild(sp1, sp2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [order](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/) with flexbox. For example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.one,
.two {
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  order: 2;
  background: red;
}


.two {
  order: 1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  2
  </div>
</div>
```

Might be a bit problematic, depending on what your markup looks like. And won't work on older browsers.

Comment: He don't have access to the DOM as noted in his question. Your solution requires editing the DOM structure before flexbox can be utilized.